# How to delete first few records from a table using SQLite query?

Tags: sqlite

I want to delete first 10 records(i.e. records 1 to 10) from my table in SQLite if the record count is 110. Only 100 records I want in my table. If record count is more than 100 then those records should be deleted, as a result if I add new records then also only 100 records should be present. How could it be possible using SQLite query, please provide your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete oldest records from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667085/delete-oldest-records-from-database)

Answer (score 7):

I gather you want to maintain 100 rows in your table by removing the first 'X' rows every time your table grows beyond 100 rows. Here is what you can do:

```
Delete from table_name where rowid IN (Select rowid from table_name limit X);
```

This will keep removing the first 'X' rows as and when your SQLite table grows.

Comment: that's ok. But I want to maintain the numbering from 1 to 100. not 11 t0 110! I hope you got my point.

Comment: @user435062: Normally you dont change the primary key to maintain the row IDs as they uniquely identify each row. Why dont you try adding another column to your table that maintains your 1 to 100 numbering?

Comment: In my table, I haven't made the RecordID as primary key.

Comment: That would remove the items in the select, you should negate the IN "NOT IN" and use an order by to make sure you get the last 100 records something like this `DELETE FROM table_name WHERE rowid NOT IN (SELECT rowid FROM table_name ORDER BY rowid LIMIT X);`

Answer (score 1):

First you have to do a select that returns the last 100 records in your table, then use the delete command to remove all ids not in the result, something like this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE NOT EXISTS in (SELECT id FROM tbl_name ORDER BY id LIMIT 100 );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried the query, but its not working. I tried the query by sing "SQLite Database Browser". It hangs when I execute the query.

Comment: `DELETE FROM Data_Table WHERE RecordID in (select RecordID from Data_Table limit 10)` This query works fine. It deletes first 10 records successfully. Now after deleting I want to update the list i.e. out of 110 records starting from 1 to 110, if I delete first 10 records then the table contains ids from 11 to 110. But I want to make it again 1 to 100. How can I perform this operation.

Comment: You dont really want to do that, trust me.. If you want to have an autoincrement value i recommend you to create it in runtime in the select. Keep the id intact or you may experiment weird behaviors in your application.

Comment: im not very experienced in sqllite, but in mysql would be something like `SELECT @m:=0;SELECT @m:=@m+1 AS counter, * FROM tbl_name...`
etc.

Answer (score -4):

`DELETE FROM {{ table }} LIMIT 0, 10`

I'm not entirely sure if that's correct and I don't have the ability to check at this moment.

Comment: DELETE FROM {{ table }} LIMIT 0, 10

The above query is also not working.

Comment: We have to compile SQLite with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` in order to get the limit clause working, else it wont work. http://sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit