# How to delete older rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a log in the mysql database and I need to keep only latest 100 records and delete the older ones. I've tried the solution from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667085/delete-oldest-records-from-database) question but that doesn't seem to work for me.

my database table has the following columns:
datetime
temp
humidity
phvalue

I don't want to use the timestamp method because i need to keep a fixed number of records. can this be done in mysql?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Delete from table t
where (Select count(*) from table 
      where datetime > t.DateTime) > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution.

`DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100)`

Inner select selects everything except newest 100 records (assuming id is auto increment) and excludes them in delete using NOT IN statement.

You can also use datetime instead of ID if datetime is in valid order.

Comment: my table doesn't have 'ID' column. so i can't really use this method.

Comment: As mentioned in answer: "You can also use datetime instead of ID if datetime is in valid order."

Answer (score 0):

If you table has a primary key suppose p_id then you can use following query

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE p_id NOT IN (SELECT p_id FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100);
```

Comment: my table doesn't have a primary id. I've stated that in the question.

Comment: then you can use the datetime column instead of id, or it would be better if you can add a primary key to the table for more accurate result.

Comment: Oh! ok.. thanks i'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other Column as the date field to find the oldest rows, but you can use the LIMIT clause to say how much rows to be deleted like this for the oldest 100 ROWS :

```
DELETE FROM table ORDER BY `datetime` DESC LIMIT 100;
```